# Как получить доступ к "телу" статьи Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Например, пользователь открывает статью через GET.

Как могу модифицировать ее перед отдачей? Есть ли для этого хук/событие?

Comment: Надо понимать, как эта статья выводится. Покажите код.

Comment: Я, честно говоря, сам не знаю, как она выводится.  Это самый стандартный wordpress из docker-compose. Ничего кастомного там нет. Тема должна быть стандартная тема.

Comment: Разберитесь хотя бы, какая тема у вас установлена - мы не можем гадать.

Comment: Twenty Twenty-Two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как могу модифицировать ее перед отдачей? Есть ли для этого
> хук/событие?

Есть. Например [the_content](https://wp-kama.ru/hook/the_content)

```
add_filter('the_content', 'the_end');
    function the_end( $text ){
        return $text . ' Конец!';
    }
```